# AdminInline and unknown IntegrityError UNIQUE constraint failed

Tags: django, django-models

```
Django Version: 3.0.4
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
UNIQUE constraint failed: store_hoursofoperation.day
```

Hello, I'm trying to resolve this error, but I don't know how to proceed. I want the `Store` model to contain multiple `HoursOfOperation`. However, this error occurs whenever I add another weekday on any store -- Store A has Monday hours, Store B will error if I add Monday hours.

I am using the default admin to include the `HoursOfOperation` within the `Store` model.

How do I stop the HoursOfOperation.day from being unique?

[image: image-of-admin-panel]

```
admin.site.register(HoursOfOperation)


class HoursOfOperationInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = HoursOfOperation
    extra = 0

@admin.register(Store)
class StoreAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        HoursOfOperationInline
    ]
```

```
WEEKDAYS = [
    (1, ("Monday")),
    (2, ("Tuesday")),
    (3, ("Wednesday")),
    (4, ("Thursday")),
    (5, ("Friday")),
    (6, ("Saturday")),
    (7, ("Sunday")),
]


class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    address_line1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address_line2 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    status_storefront = models.BooleanField(
        help_text="Is the storefront open to customers?"
    )
    status_takeout = models.BooleanField(
        help_text="Is takeout available for customers?"
    )
    status_delivery = models.BooleanField(
        help_text="What is the delivery service? [No, Yes, Custom]"
    )
    status_delivery_service = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    anchor_id = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    hours = models.Many

    @property
    def storefront(self):
        return "Yes" if self.status_storefront else "No"

    @property
    def takeout(self):
        return "Yes" if self.status_takeout else "No"

    @property
    def delivery(self):
        if self.status_delivery:
            if self.status_delivery_service:
                return self.status_delivery_service
            return "Yes"
        else:
            return "No"



class HoursOfOperation(models.Model):
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    day = models.IntegerField(choices=WEEKDAYS)
    time_open = models.TimeField(
        auto_now=False,
        auto_now_add=False,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    time_close = models.TimeField(
        auto_now=False,
        auto_now_add=False,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )   

    def get_day_display(self):
        return WEEKDAYS[self.day]

    @property
    def open(self):
        if self.time_open and self.time_close:
            return self.time_open
        else:
            return "Closed"

    @property
    def close(self):
        if self.time_open and self.time_close:
            return self.time_close
        else:
            return ""

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('time_open', 'time_close')
```

Comment: Do you have any unapplied migrations? Looks like you have a unique index on the "day" field but not on your model, do you get changes when you run `manage.py makemigrations`?

Comment: @IainShelvington Oh wow... I must have forgotten to run ```manage.py migrate``` after all my back and forth modifications. ```manage.py makemigrations``` removed the constraint, but it didn't work until after ```manage.py migrate```. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@IainShelvington's comment on running `manage.py makemigrations` did it.

Even if you think you've run `manage.py makemigrations` and `manage.py migrate`, double check your code *and* run it one more time before giving up.